# How to detect when a console application stopped by a scheduled task in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a console application that runs for a specified period of time. In case of the application runs out of the specified time then there a scheduled job that stops the application.

Could you please me know if there is any way to detect when the application stopped by the scheduler?

I have already tried a couple of things e.g. catch the event on `CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` and implementing the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` but none of them worked.

Thanks, in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: How does the scheduled job terminate the task?

Comment: I'd usually only recommend having Task Scheduler kill a program if you're unable to change the code of the program you're running - it's a very crude sledgehammer approach. Since you're contemplating changing the code of this program, why not implement the timeout internally - then when it happens, there's nothing to *detect* because it's *your code* that's going to cause the shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this article. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040722-00/?p=38373 that explains that killing process can't be handled by application. You have to exit your consoleapp in a nice way rather just killing its process

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, it looks like not possible to detect in the code. I will check for another ways to terminating the application.

Comment: Also consider solutions that James World provided. That being put closing logic inside console app itself if this is not possible maybe create seperate background service app that could check in intervals if your console app lives and if not do some stuff

Answer (score 1):

If the process is being killed, you can't detect that in the process. You'll need a different solution. Options include having a separate "watcher" process, but my guess it that would be unnecessarily complex here.

I would probably put a canary thread in the process itself that uses a timer and cancellation token to signal the task it should cleanly abort.

The same console app could detect if an instance of itself is already running (e.g. hung) on start-up and manage a process-kill itself. That way all the logic is in one place, and you don't need the scheduled task to do anything fancy.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will look for other options.